# The return type of useQuery's data is unknown

Tags: typescript, axios, react-query, react-custom-hooks

I made a custom Hook called useRequest using react-query.

Through him, a custom Hook called useUser is created, and in the process, the data type is evaluated as unknown.

I tried several methods, but all failed.

But data fetching works fine.

How can I solve the above type?

```js
//useUser.tsx
const useUser = ({ redirectTo, redirectIfFound }: IParams) => {
  const { data, error } = useRequest("authed", isAuthed);
  const [calledPush, setCalledPush] = useState(false);
  const user = data?.data;   //Type error: Object is of type 'unknown'.
  const hasUser = user;
...
```

```js
//auth.service.ts
async isAuthedUser() {
    const { data } = await super.get("/auth/validate", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${TokenProvider.get("accessToken")}`,
      },
    });

    return data;
  }

//auth.ts
const isAuthed = () => authService.isAuthedUser();
```

```js
//useRequest.ts

export const useRequest = (request: QueryKey, func: QueryFunction, options?: UseQueryOptions) => useQuery(request, func, options);
```

Answer (score 3):

`UseQueryOptions` has 4 generics, and by omitting them, they will fall back to the default values of the generics, which is `unknown`.

It is generally not advised to build low-level abstractions where you allow to pass all options in. This particular `useRequest` hook serves no real value.

If you really want to do that, you have to use all generics like we do internally for react-query:

```
export function useRequest<
  TQueryFnData = unknown,
  TError = unknown,
  TData = TQueryFnData,
  TQueryKey extends QueryKey = QueryKey,
>(
  queryKey: TQueryKey,
  queryFn: QueryFunction<TQueryFnData, TQueryKey>,
  options?: Omit<
    UseQueryOptions<TQueryFnData, TError, TData, TQueryKey>,
    'queryKey' | 'queryFn'
  >,
) {
  return useQuery(queryKey, queryFn, options)
}
```

You'll still remove the latest feature we added, which infers type of `data` better if `initialData` is passed as option. If you want to replicate that, you need overloads. Again, probably not worth it.

My recommendation is that `useUser` should just call `useQuery` directly, unless you have a really good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

1. I had same issue with Typescript and react-query, same error `Object is of type 'unknown'.` Installing this devDependency "**@types/react-query**" helped me somehow. I am using VS Code editor and I think that helped with type suggestions. This might help.

`npm i --save-dev @types/react-query`

2. I suggest you add return value to your `useRequest()` function. Something like `UseQueryResult<UseRequestResult>`. `UseRequestResult` should be interface with User type. Judging from the rest of the code, I think thats what you are expecting to receive...

```
import { useQuery, UseQueryResult } from "@tanstack/react-query";

type User = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    // and the rest of properties you need
}
interface UseRequestResult {
    user: User,
    error: Error,
}
function useRequest(/* arguments */): UseQueryResult<UseRequestResult> {
    // your implementation
}
```

3. I suggest you add empty user object as default.

```
//useUser.tsx
...
const { data: {user: {}}, error } = useRequest("authed", isAuthed);
const user = data.user;
...
```